# How do we operationally define kitniyos?

Tags: minhag, food, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

I've heard/read much debate on whether certain plants qualify as kitniyos, such as snow peas and quinoa. What exactly halachically defines "kitniyos?" is it based on what was popular in [13th century](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mordechai) Germany, the biological definition of a legume, or something else?

Answer (score 5):

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein writes that if a custom developed about it at whatever point in time, for whatever reason, it's kitniyos; if not, then not.

**Regarding peanuts** -- he doesn't say that they're not kitniyos because they're too new. He says there were different customs in different places, and where he came from had no custom against them. But if you know your ancestors developed the custom to treat peanuts as kitniyos, then they're treated as such.

Rav Moshe also suggests the possibility that at some point in time, rabbis ceased from adding more plants to the kitniyos list so there would still be enough things left to eat on Pesach!

Comment: thats correct but the way he expresses this is to say only that which is in the rema and the gemara are kitniyot, however whatever is not eaten in your community shouldnt be eaten by you.  The point I was making was that there is not categorical definition of kitniyot based on the genetics or the physical makeup of any plant.  Whatever isnt eaten on pessach because of kitniyot is kitniyot whether it is a fruit a veggie or a legume.

Comment: @EytanYammer I think the language is "kadmonim", need not be in the Rema. Rema says caraway ("kimmel") isn't kitniyos but it has since become prohibited.

Comment: I think that we agree.  I will delete my comment below as it has caused confusion.  I am not looking at the teshuvah right now but if memory serves you are correct.

Comment: FWIW, it's really funny to see old Maxwell House haggados (from the 1960's), proudly advertising Kosher for Passover Planter's Peanut Oil.  How times have changed.

Answer (score 2):

The word kitnyios means legumes.  However, it has come to mean any of a variety of foods from which different groups of Jews abstain on Pesach.

There is no set standard list of what is considered kitnyios, or even a set criteria of why foods might be considered kitnyios.

The gemara Pesachim 35a clearly states that only five foods can possibly become chametz:  wheat, barley, oats, spelt, rye.  Furthermore, [it explicitly rules out rice and millet!](http://www.tzemachdovid.org/Vsamachta/Pesach01/kitnios.shtml)

Yet rice, millet, beans, and other starchy, staple foods have been categorized as "kitnyios" by Ashkenazi communities for centuries.

When crops from the New World started to arrive in Europe, the kitnyios question renewed.  Corn (maize) became kitnyios because of [a linguistic error.](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/871998/jewish/Know-Thy-Beans.htm)

Blessedly, the potato escaped such scrutiny: however, the Chaye Adam wanted to [consider potatoes as kitnyios as well](http://kitniyos.blogspot.com/)

Foods that have only recently hit the Jewish scene, such as quinoa, are [not considered kitnyios](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6559/1095) - although this plant has a slightly grain-like feel to it.

In summary, kitnyios has no specific definition.  It is a custom.  My personal feeling is, if such an illogical custom were to impinge our eating all year round, we would have done away with it by now.  However, since it only applies for seven days (eight in the Diaspora), and it comes at a time of year when we are already significantly alerting our regular food habits, the ban of kitnyios on Pesach is here to stay.

Comment: I think the point about corn is questionable.  I don't agree that it was a "linguistic error".  Unlike potatoes, corn (maize) is biologically a grain.

Comment: about your last point, it sounds a bit harsh. However, Rabbi Belsky ZT"L told me this point about why we have so many chumros on Pesach, because we can handle chumros for just one week, so people are quick to accept them. This is not a criticism on chumros, it is a positive thing about how we do not accept chumros which are too difficult for people.

Answer (score 1):

[Kashrut.com](http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/kitniot_list/) publishes a list of what is regarded as kitniyot. Also see [OU Kitniyot List](https://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/kitniyot-list/) and [What is Kitnityot](https://oukosher.org/passover/articles/what-is-kitniyot/) for a general explanation. Your main question as to the reasoning behind *kitniyot* is brought up in the *Mishna Berurah*.

> The Mishnah Berurah (453:6 & 464:5) cites three reasons for the minhag
>   (a) kitniyot is harvested and processed in the same manner as chametz,
>   (b) it is ground into flour and baked just like chametz [so people may
>   mistakenly believe that if they can eat kitniyot, they can also eat
>   chametz], ( c ) it may have chametz grains mixed into it [so people
>   who eat kitniyot may inadvertently be eating chametz]. Although
>   initially there were those who objected to the minhag, it has become
>   an accepted part of Pesach in all Ashkenazic communities.

As regards peanuts:

> Iggeros Moshe (O.C. III:63) assumes that peanuts are not kitniyot but
>   notes that some have a custom to be machmir.

The *Igros Moshe* notes that this is a matter of minhag within a community and that as long as something has not previously been considered *kitniyot*, it will not be *added* to the list. However, those that have a minhag to treat something as *kitniyot* should continue to do so (as an example, peanuts).

> Iggeros Moshe explains that the minhag to not eat kitniyot developed
>   differently than other minhagim and therefore rules that only foods
>   which we know were specifically included in the minhag are forbidden.
>   [See also Chok Yaakov 453:9 who makes a similar point]. With this he
>   explains the generally accepted custom to not consider potatoes to be
>   kitniyot even though logically they should be, as follows: the minhag
>   of kitniyot can be dated back at least until Maharil, who died in
>   1427, and potatoes didn’t come to Europe until the 16th century, so
>   potatoes were a “new” vegetable which wasn’t included in the minhag.
>   An important “exception” to the aforementioned rule that “new”
>   vegetables aren’t included in the minhag, is corn/maize which Mishnah
>   Berurah 453:4 and others rule is kitniyot even though it was
>   introduced to Europe after the minhag had already begun.
>
> As a rule, spices are not considered to be kitniyot and Rema 453:1
>   makes a point of noting that anise/dill and coriander are not
>   kitniyot. Taz 462:3 notes that all spices should be checked before
>   Pesach to establish that no chametz-grains are mixed in, and elsewhere
>   Taz (453:1) specifically notes that anise and coriander seeds should
>   be thoroughly checked. In addition, Taz and Magen Avraham (453:3)
>   discuss whether fennel, cumin and caraway seeds (i.e. three variations
>   of “Kimmel” ) can possibly be checked (and used) for Pesach. Thus, as
>   a rule, spices are not kitniyot but require special care to guarantee
>   that no chametz-grains are mixed into them. Some hashgochos consider
>   fenugreek to be kitniyot while others do not, and the surprising
>   ramifications of this question will be noted towards the end of the
>   article.