# Which seeds are considered kitniyot?

Tags: passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15251/5275) says:

> There is no set standard list of what is considered kitniyos, or even
>   a set criteria of why foods might be considered kitniyos.

I don't think this is completely true. Granted that the rules seem to change every few years, but someone seems to be setting a standard regarding seeds, in particular. This is where I'm unclear.

I understand some of the common ones that haven't been around for along time like sesame and mustard seeds. But I'm not sure about other spice seeds like nutmeg, cumin, anise, and coriander, and any others.

Is there a current list that someone has published that defines what's allowed and what isn't?

Comment: @DoubleAA see recent edits.

Comment: [Kashrut.com](http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/kitniot_list/) publishes a list of what is regarded as kitniyot. Also see [OU Kitniyot List](https://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/kitniyot-list/) and [What is Kitnityot](https://oukosher.org/passover/articles/what-is-kitniyot/) for a general explanation.

Comment: @DoubleAA Note that the duplicate being pointed to is itself marked as a duplicate of [How do we operationally define kitniyos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15249/how-do-we-operationally-define-kitniyos). I think you should change the pointer.

Comment: @sabbahillel Perfect! Thank you. Interestingly, OU includes rapessed as kitniyot, but I think I have seen KP rapeseed oil.

Comment: It is a machlokes as we see at http://lifeinisrael.blogspot.com/2014/04/rabbanut-says-canola-oil-is-not-kitniyot.html and http://www.srugim.co.il/73290-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95-%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%A0